# Know specified fields on serverside in GraphQL / Sangria-Graphql

Tags: scala, graphql, sangria

When a client sends a request, I want to know what are the fields client has requested for data. For example,

```
{
  user {
    name
    address
  }
}
```

In the above request, client has requested `name` field and `address` field of the user. how do I know/get these specified fields i.e. name and address in the sangria-graphql Server while executing the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use `4th` parameter in `resolve()`

```
resolve: (obj, args, auth, fieldASTs) => {
    /* all your fields are present in selections
       please check the fieldASTs JSON path it may vary if you are using relay
                                                                connections */
  const requiredFields = fieldASTs.fieldNodes[0].selectionSet.selections.map(
      (set) => set.name.value
   );
  // requiredFields will contain the name and address
}
/* fieldASTs contains fieldNames, fieldNodes and every details about your Schema 
 you can get your specified fields inside fieldNodes like */
```

Comment: It is graphql-js right? Can you tell me how to achieve same with sangria-graphql? Anyway, I'll try to figure it out in sangria. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I just figured it out. I have modified my code to `resolve = c => {c.astFields.head.selections.map(fld => println(fld.renderCompact));` in Field of QueryType. Thank you.

Comment: That's Great. Happy Coding

Comment: @ra-ka @p0k8_ Although it is possible to work directly with AST, it is much more involving since you also need to consider things like inline fragments, frangent spreads, `@include` and `@skip` directives, etc. You also need to consider all `fieldNodes`/`astFields` and not just the first one. In Sangria I would recommend you use projections for this, which considers all things I described above: http://sangria-graphql.org/learn/#projections

Comment: @tenshi Can you give me some example codes on how to use the projector? I could not find any usage example in your given link. Btw, this is what I am trying to achieve - limit fields in query result.

Comment: yes, that should be considered if certain `connectionFields` are used in relay connection the path may differ

Comment: @RaKa there are no examples in the docs (I will try to add some soon), but maybe this spec can help a bit: https://github.com/sangria-graphql/sangria/blob/master/src/test/scala/sangria/execution/ProjectorSpec.scala

Comment: @tenshi Using projection is way efficient than what I used previously. e.g. I can provide field depth etc. btw, your link example helped me a lot. Thank you.